# Cytoscape.js will not run cose-bilken layout in React

Tags: reactjs, cytoscape.js

I'm using the [react-cytoscape](https://github.com/plotly/react-cytoscapejs) package with a simple dataset returned from an async `fetch` call.

Here is my class in full.  When run, all elements are pushed to (0,0) on top of each.  The `cose` layout does not seem to run.  The data does not contain positions.

```
import React, { FC, useState } from 'react';
import Card from 'react-bootstrap/Card'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import Container from 'react-bootstrap/Container'
import Row from 'react-bootstrap/Row'
import Col from 'react-bootstrap/Col'
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome'
import { faSquare } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons'

import Cytoscape from 'cytoscape';
//import COSEBilkent from 'cytoscape-cose-bilkent';
import coseBilkent from 'cytoscape-cose-bilkent';
import CytoscapeComponent from 'react-cytoscapejs';
//Cytoscape.use(COSEBilkent);
Cytoscape.use(coseBilkent);

 class ContactNetworkContainer extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {data:[], layout: {name: 'cose-bilkent'}};
        //this.state = {data:[], layout: {name: 'random'}};
        //this.state = {data:[], layout: {name: 'preset'}};
    }
    componentDidMount() {
        fetch('api/v1/mock/contactnetwork/1')
        .then((response) => response.json())
            .then(json => this.setState({data: json}))
    }
     render( ) {
         return (
             <>
                 <div className="row ml-3">
                                <div className="col-md-12 p-0" style={{backgroundColor:"green"}}>
                                    <CytoscapeComponent
                                        cy={(cy) => {this.cy = cy}}
                                        layout = {{name: 'random'}}
                                     elements={this.state.data}
                                     style = {{width: '600px', height: '300px'}}
                                        //layout = {{name: 'grid', rows: 1}}
                                     layout = {this.state.layout}
                                 />
                             </div>
                         </div>
                     </>
         )
    }
 }

 export default ContactNetworkContainer;
```

Answer (score 0):

I was running into the same issue. Resolved by chaning import to:

```
import CytoscapeComponent from 'react-cytoscapejs/src';
```

[Full solution outline](https://github.com/plotly/react-cytoscapejs/issues/8)